# HKStatisticsCollectionQuery pulling data for each week of the month

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, healthkit

I'm trying to create a chart that displays a month's worth of data vs the past month's data broken up by week.

For example viewing the chart today would show July vs June, there would be 5 points on each graph with the following dates:

June: 1-8, 9-15, 16-22, 23-29, 30
July: 1-8, 9-15, 16-22, 23-29, 30-31

The predicate looks like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:self.pastStartDate endDate:self.currentEndDate options:HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate];
```

where `self.pastStartDate` is the first of last month and `self.currentEndDate` is the last of the current month.

We then set up the query like so

```
HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:quantityType quantitySamplePredicate:predicate options:HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteAverage anchorDate:self.pastStartDate intervalComponents:self.interval];
```

So for the month, `self.interval.day = 7` is set so that we pull a week's worth of data at every interval.  The problem is that this interval is not calendar aware, so it doesn't know that the final data point for the last month should only have 1 day, therefore we are getting some overlap.

We have also tried `self.interval.weekOfMonth = 1` but again, the interval does not know which month it is in so this is not working either.

Is there a way to create the interval based on the calendar so that it doesn't include more than the end of the month in a given interval?

Comment: So they're not exact intervals, right? In which case you should probably be using a day interval and grouping those into week/week/part of week dynamically.